# I am trying to extract plain text from search result on certain website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm learning python on my own pace and have been stuck on an issue.
I am trying to display the result of a search as plain text by running a python script on command line. This is what I have; it opens Firefox, launches the website and auto fills the search box with the address and as you can see in the bottom right corner it gives you a map reference.

```
import html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.street-directory.com.au/vic")

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("searchtxt")
elem.send_keys("595 Little Collins Street, Melbourne, VIC 3000" + Keys.RETURN)
```

No matter what I have tried I wasn't able to get the plain text result of that box's content to display.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the content in the div with `info-lyr-container` class?

Comment: If you look at that webpage with that address entered, on the right hand bottom corner you get a map reference in red colour, in this example with the above address it is "43 F9" all i need is that text.  Firefox inspector is showing me is div id= "MapReference Number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the piece of code which should work.

```
url = r"https://www.street-directory.com.au/vic"
# navigate to url
driver.get(url)
# get the current map ref number (we have to wait until this is updated when new address is entered)
oldMapRefNumber = driver.find_element_by_id("MapReference Number").text
# wait for the search
search = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"searchtxt")))
# send the address and hit enter
address = "595 Little Collins Street, Melbourne, VIC 3000"
search.send_keys( address + Keys.RETURN)
# wait the popup to display with the specified address (optional)
WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='info-lyr-prop-top']")))
# wait until the old map ref number is updated
WebDriverWait(driver,60).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='MapReference Number'][.='" +oldMapRefNumber + "']")))
# get the new map ref number
mapRefNumber = driver.find_element_by_id("MapReference Number").text
# print the new map ref number
print(mapRefNumber)
```

Output:

> 43 F9

Comment: Mate I would like to thank you very very much, that is exactly what I needed. For any one that is interested in what I was trying to achieve is this; I wanted a user to enter an address and receieve the melway reference.